# How do I record the frequency of numbers inputted by a user using functions in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, loops, frequency

Hey there i'm currently developing a lotto type game and one of my requirements is to record the frequency of the numbers inputted by the user and then display them if the users wishes to see them. The program also must be modular hence the functions.

My problem is that i can't seem to figure out how to keep track of the numbers I tried numerous things and this is the closest I've gotten...

```
void num_free(int *picked_nums)
{
    static int elements[MAX] = { 0 };
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
        if (*(picked_nums + i) == i)
        {
            elements[i]++;
        }

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        if (elements[i] != 0)
        {
            printf("\nThe amount of times you chose %d is %d", i, elements[i]);
        }
    }

    printf("\nEnter any key to return to main menu");
    getchar();
}
```

The output of this every time i run it no matter the input is

"The amount of times you chose 11 is 1"

I'm really clueless as to what to do next so any and all help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The user can play multiple rounds and thats how the frequency of the numbers can add up.

Comment: Please clarify: are the numbers in a lotto draw not required to be unique?? How can a user pick a number more than once for a draw?

Comment: my apologies they can play multiple rounds

Comment: Okay, so just define a `number_history` array that increments the value for each number (that matches the index in the array) each time a number is picked.

Comment: Is that not what i'd doing with the elements array ?

Comment: I'm sorry i don't really understand

Comment: Okay, I overlooked that the `elements` array was `static`. Is this function called for _every_ draw, or only if the user chooses?

Comment: Everytime the user enters in a new set of numbers that goes into an array picked_nums which is in main ()

Comment: I understand that, but if this function is not called for *every* draw, then the history is not updated for *that* draw. And you don't need to loop over the entire range of `MAX`, just do `for (i = 0; i < draw count; i++) { elements[picked_nums[i]]++;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is how you count and store the numbers:

```
if (*(picked_nums + i) == i)
{
    elements[i]++;
}
```

Your `i` is moving and at the same time the element chosen from `picked_nums` is moving. This loop will not count or store properly.

The provided solution assumes that picked numbers are stored in the `numbers` array. I assumed that numbers are in 1 to 64 range.  You can adjust program to your needs. Test provided:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void num_free(int picked_nums[], int size )
{
    static int elements[65] = { 0 }; // numbers can be from 1 to 64 range
    int i;

    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        int n = picked_nums[j];

        for (i = 1; i < 65; i++)   // numbers can be from 1 to 64 range
        {  
            if ( n == i)
            {
                elements[i] = elements[i]+1;
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 65; i++)
    {
        if (elements[i] != 0)
        {
            printf("\nThe amount of times you chose %d is %d", i, elements[i]);
        }
    }

   // printf("\nEnter any key to return to main menu");
   // getchar();
}

// array of entered numbers:
int numbers[] = { 2, 2, 2, 40, 7, 7, 8, 9, 40 };

int main(void) {

    num_free(numbers, 9); // call with sizeof numbers

    return 0;
}
```

Test:

```
The amount of times you chose 2 is 3                                                                                                          
The amount of times you chose 7 is 2                                                                                                          
The amount of times you chose 8 is 1                                                                                                          
The amount of times you chose 9 is 1                                                                                                          
The amount of times you chose 40 is 2
```

Comment: What does the int size do?

Comment: This is the number of elements in `int picked_nums`

Comment: AH okay i understand now thank you so much for your help haha

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem in your code is here:

```
if (*(picked_nums + i) == i)
{
    elements[i]++;
}
```

you actually check if the i-th number the user chose equals to i. That means that increment is done only in that case - which is not what you want (if I got you right).

I think you should give up the `if` statement, and, assuming that the user chooses only non-negative numbers (and that the `elements` array is properly zeroed at the beginning), do this:

```
elements[picked_nums[i]]++;
```

Namely, you increment the array cell matching the chosen number (and the `i` is only the index you use to iterate the `picked_num` array).